# Hyperlink issue in the stack overflow talent - case studies page

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, stack-overflow-talent

In the [Stack Overflow Talent Case Studies page](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent/case-studies)'s bottom, there is a section for the feedback, it was written by the leadership person of the company about the Stack Overflow Talent.

The company name along with the person name is display as a hyperlink. Clicking on the link, it simply redirect the case studies page only instead of that the specific company's case studies page.

For an example in the screenshot the feedback is written by the CEO of Server Density company, clicking on the link it should redirect to [its case study page](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent/case-studies/server-density) and not the [same page](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent/case-studies) again

[image: Case studies page]

Comment: Only one of the three quotes there even correlate to an actual case study. The other two don't have case studies listed on that page. But I don't really understand the point of linking to the same page again. Seems like the quotes should just be plain text. There might also be a plan there for linking to something in the future that just isn't available yet.

Comment: @animuson: Yes. Plain text won't make any confusion.